# Tablet PC hardware for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: tablet, devices, ubuntu-touch

I'm in need of an e-book reader, and considering it'd be yet another thing to throw into my student bag I want to look into tablet computing.

Now, I don't really have much love for Apple's stuff, so please do not recommend the iPad; iPad like, yes.

Specifically, I'm looking for a touchscreen tablet that will be able to make use of Ubuntu/Jolicloud/whatever and allow me to browse the web, play music, watch videos and read books. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of currently tablet like devices are still coming to the market. As far as I know there are currently *no* tablet like devices running Ubuntu, though in the near future there will be a whole bunch running Android and/or Meego. If I were you I'd look into the Samsung Galaxy Tab which is due to be released very soon.

Comment: The Galaxy Tab...hmmm...isn't that the one with the offical Android marketplace? Do you know if I'd be able to install another OS on there if I need to?

Comment: Yes it has the Android Market and its not been released to the public yet, so nope, nobody has tried to get Ubuntu running on it (or are there any promises it will work).

Answer (score 0):

Do what u want but I would suggest Acer Aspire 1825ptz - you will need to work to get the touchscreen working...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1483973